# Avoid repeating records displaying in MySQL / PHP

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, duplicates

This is a very basic PHP MySQL question that I need answered.

When displaying data from a table, I need to avoid/prevent duplicates.  I am trying to populate a drop down menu with a list of countries from the database.  So that... If there are many records with the **Country** "US" ... it will only display ONCE in the drop down list.  I'm not sure if this should be MySQL coding or PHP coding.  ??

DB INFO:

table:  dealers

field:  Country

*If possible, please post the exact php and/or MySQL coding that can be COPY/PASTED directly into my code.*

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL that you want is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Country
FROM dealers
```

Comment: This does not work:  
$country_post = $_POST['Country']; 
$country_post = "US"; 
$query="SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM dealers"; 
 
It still displays ALL records with Country "US".

Comment: (*I am working with code from another programmer.) I had to keep paring down the code.  In the many lines of code, I found ANOTHER query hanging around!!  This was overriding my "DISTINCT" query.  Your code above works just fine.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `distinct` keyword to get unique records.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `field1`FROM `table1`
```

Comment: what will be the query for structure like, fetching data from multiple tables in one query

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across the same issue in my application.  I had joined two tables from my database and for the life of me couldn't figure out how to get rid of the duplicate data that was coming from the table I joined.  After doing a little research I found that using `DISTINCT` would only give me the values that were different.  This solved my problem and should solve yours as well.

Answer (score 0):

select DISTINCT document_type,document_subtype,document  from document_details where employee_id='ERP170102547549543' ORDER BY document_type ASC

Comment: i want to avoid repeating fields

Comment: any suggestions

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.